# Should I use S3 data frames in my package?

Tags: r, amazon-s3, tidyverse, r-s4

I have a package which uses a data.frame based S4 class:

```
setClass(Class="foobar",
  slots=c(a="character", b="character", c="character"),
  contains="data.frame")
```

Works as intended. However, I observe weird warnings when combining with tidyverse:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:5)
df2 <- new("foobar", df)
as_tibble(df2)
```

The last statement incites a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In class(x) <- c(subclass, tibble_class) :
  Setting class(x) to multiple strings ("tbl_df", "tbl", ...); result will no longer be an S4 object
```

This is because tidyverse [does not support S4 data frames](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2193). This can be circumvented in downstream code by using `asS3(df)`. However, users of my package may be puzzled if they see these warnings. I am now faced with the following choices and I don't really know which would be the most reasonable and correct:

- Keep the S4 model and hope that the users won't mind seeing this warning each time they pass my data frames into something else.
- Use S3. However, I already have another S4 class defined in published versions of my package. I am afraid that I would break someones code.
- Mix S3 and S4. Is it even allowed?

Is there another solution I might be overlooking?

Comment: Do you NEED S4 functionality? If in doubt, go with the simplest solution, which would be S3 in this case

Comment: Is it just `as_tibble`? Would something like `as_tibble.foobar <- function(x, ...) as_tibble(asS3(x))` work well-enough?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, `asS3` works, but I don't use tibbles in my package. I am worried about users who might. Maybe @HongOoi is right and I should just use S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no brilliant solution to this which is entirely within your control.

The `tidyverse` package may call `class<-` on any data-frame-like object given to it, and as you have seen this will destroy the S4 nature of any object. This can't be worked around by (for instance) defining a method for `coerce` or calling `setAs`, as `class<-` doesn't use that mechanism. (`class<-` isn't generic either, you can't set a method for it.) The only way to make `tidyverse` support S4 is for `tidyverse`'s author to alter the code to use `as` or similar, and it doesn't look like that is top of their to-do-list.

You are correct to be worried about dramatically altering the way your class works when you have released a version of your package already with an S4 class.

If:

- your package is quite new and doesn't yet have many users;
- you can do all you need to do with S3; and
- you don't know of another package which has built new classes on top of yours

then it may be best to redefine it as S3, and include a message when your package is installed or loaded to say

> thanks for installing myPackage v2. Code may be incompatible with v1.2 or earlier; see help(blah) for details

otherwise, stick with S4.

You can't exactly mix S3 and S4 for class definitions (you can for method definitions). The closest you can come is `setOldClass` which registers a S3 class as an S4 one (whereas you wanted the opposite). Still, that may help you achieve "you can do all you need to do with S3" above.

One other possibility is to define your own version of `class<-` which checks to see if an object of S4 class `foobar` is attempting to be coerced to `S3` and calls the ordinary `class<-` if not. The cure is probably worse than the disease in this case; this will slow down *all* future S3 class conversions (since `class<-` is now an ordinary function call, not a primitive) but it should work in principle. Another reason that it is not recommended is that you are relying on no other package higher in the search path doing something similar (what if another package author had the same issue and wanted to do the same trick? Then the results would depend on which package was higher up the `search` path!)

Comment: This is interesting; can you expand on "You can't exactly mix S3 and S4 for class definitions (you can for method definitions)"? My particular question is whether I can define two separate classes in my package, one S3 and one S4. I think that would be bad style, but maybe it would be a good solution...

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I thought you meant have one class definition which was somehow for a S3 and S4 class. You can certainly have two entirely distinct classes (and perhaps an `as` method to convert between them) — it will make your own method dispatch harder to do, but the problems may be able to be dealt with

Comment: No, not even that. I have an S4 class for one purpose, call it "x". Now I wanted to have another class entirely for another purpose and another type of objects, and wrote it as S4, call it "y". If I decide to use S3 for the y class, should I rewrite the y class as S3? So that the package uses only one OO model?

Comment: Oh, that's relatively inoffensive. For the most part, the end user doesn't have to interact with the class system so using both isn't much of a problem. Sorry, I thought you were having a more difficult problem! For the S3 class, it might be worth calling `setOldClass` so it works with S4 as well though.